Ways to mute audio interface's recording device via Windows Sound Control Panel
Environment: Windows 10
Device: Teyun Q12 audio interface
What happens: In Sound Control Panel > Recording tab > Right-clicking the interface's recording device > Levels tab > Clicking the speaker icon or setting the slider to left most does not mute said device
Sound Control Panel image
What is expected: Recording device should be muted
I tried using nirsoft tools to no avail. So far the only way I've found to mute on software side is by disabling the device.
I found that Voicemeeter's virtual cables behave similarly. And that they made another program(VAIO Control Panel) that ties into Windows Sound Control Panel, making it mute-able there. So it seems to be possible? I'm open to making my own program for it if need be, just not sure where to start. But if there are methods, please do let me know.
I specifically prefer muting it via Sound Control Panel so I can assign a global hotkey to mute it. Disabling/Enabling does not work well for already running applications.
